# Find if process is alive in windows

Tags: java, php, windows, cmd

**Short version:**

- In windows with the PID, my program needs to find out if my process still running/alive.

In linux I would just use "grep pid" and all would be done, anything like that in windows?

**Longer version:**

I'm making a php(7) system on windows, which runs a bluetooth Java server. My system runs the server through command line and saves the PID:

```
    $command = 'java -jar app\InterfaceBluetooth.jar /k > storage\logs\bluetoothServerToten.txt';
    $descriptorspec = array (
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w")
    );

    if(is_resource($prog = proc_open("start /b " . $command, $descriptorspec, $pipes))){
        $ppid = proc_get_status($prog)['pid'];
    }// IF
    else{
        // error stuff
        exit();
    }// ELSE

    $output = array_filter(explode(" ", shell_exec("wmic process get parentprocessid,processid | find \"$ppid\"")));
    array_pop($output);
    $pid = end($output);
```

So, at this point the process is up and running  and I have the PID.

Now, it's important that the user could know for sure that the server is running. In someway, my system needs to check this, which goes back to the short version.

Does not matter how, php 7 function, command line or another way, just to my system be able to find out if it is running.

Comment: do you have control over bluetooth server source code? If so, into your bluetooth server implement simple `hello-service` which listens to a special port. Then in your other application just send a network packet to this hello-port and wait for response. If server responds, then it is up and running, otherwise it is not. This way is better than memorizing and dealing with process id tokens.

Comment: You are asking for two different things: `1` Given a PID, how do I know that the process has reached a stage where it can communicate? `2` Given a PID, how do I know that a process is still running and responding to requests? The answer to either question could be a different one.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I did made the bluetooth server, but i choose to do it in java because I wasn't capable to do this communicattion in PHP or JS. Send a network packet would be the best way by far, just not an option at the time.

Comment: @IInspectable My is question is the second one "Given a PID, how do I know that a process is still running and responding to requests"

Comment: Easiest solution: Listen for disconnect events of the pipe you are using as the communication transport.

Comment: @Moisés you are already using `wmic` command to find the PID, why not use it to check the health of your process now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is equivalent of `ps aux | grep PID`, try `tasklist /nh /fi "pid eq PID"`.

Comment: ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized. 
:(

Comment: Substitute your process ID in place of `PID`, e.g. if your process id is 1423, the query would be `tasklist /nh /fi "pid eq 1423"`

Comment: I don't belive that.. I was replacing "pid eq PID" for the PID (tasklist /nh /fi 1234) ¬¬.. but there it goes 50 bounty ^^"

Answer (score 4):

Simply execute command below and catch the output:

```
TASKLIST /v /fi "PID eq your_pid"
```

Comment: ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized. 
:(